# ZF2 ViewJsonStrategy and ZFCUser

Tags: php, json, zend-framework2

I have a ZF2 based web application that only responds with JSON.  I am following the how-to from http://www.packtpub.com/zend-framework-2-application-development/book

Well they did not implement the site with ZFCUser.. and now I would like to switch to using it.  Ive successfully loaded the modules, but realized the `view_manager` is trying to serve login pages with html etc etc..

My **global.php** indicating I always respond with JSON

```
),
'view_manager' => array(
    'strategies' => array(
        'ViewJsonStrategy',
    ),
),
```

I imagine I need to override the controller inside `../vender/zf-commons/zfc-user` and somehow knock out all this HTML `../view/` related stuff?  All those resources are not needed on this server, since the view is done elsewhere.  Can `ZFCUser` do this properly, securely..? Or should I stick with their original custom `User` implementation (not ideal imo)

**Error occurring**

I'm guessing since I don't have any view_manager except the above.. I should write a module to handle all errors and display a simple json error message, but I thought I already had that in the event listener..

```
  [Tue Apr 22 17:54:55.759143 2014] [:error] [pid 5835] [client 127.0.0.1:49695] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend\\View\\Exception\\RuntimeException' with message 'Zend\\View\\Renderer\\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "error"; resolver could not resolve to a file' in /var/www/html/zf2project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php:499\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/zf2project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/View.php(205): Zend\\View\\Renderer\\PhpRenderer->render(Object(Zend\\View\\Model\\ViewModel))\n#1 /var/www/html/zf2project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/View.php(233): Zend\\View\\View->render(Object(Zend\\View\\Model\\ViewModel))\n#2 /var/www/html/zf2project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/View.php(198): Zend\\View\\View->renderChildren(Object(Zend\\View\\Model\\ViewModel))\n#3 /var/www/html/zf2project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/View/Http/DefaultRenderingStrategy.php(102): Zend\\View\\View->render(Object(Zend\\View\\Model\\ViewModel))\n#4 [internal function]: Zend\\Mvc\\View\\Http\\Defa in /var/www/html/zf2project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php on line 499
[Tue Apr 22 17:59:18.892507 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5829] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Apr 22 17:59:19.983382 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5973] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Apr 22 17:59:19.983556 2014] [core:notice] [pid 5973] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the one listed is the only 'view_manager' config you need to add the configuration part for error/404 pages. Also your error `Unable to render template "error"` make me think you don't have it.

This is the 'view_manager' config of the ZF2 skeleton application, you should add config keys for error handling.

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
    'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
    'template_map' => array(
        'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
        'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
        'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
        'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
```

Did you used one of the [adviced methods](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zendtool.introduction.html) to scaffold your ZF2 app? If yes you should have the Application module well configured.

About the Json response and ZFCUser you'll need to create a controller that extends the ZfcUser\Controller\UserController, then overwrite the Invokable service for this controller (it is used for routing, check the routes configs in the ZfcUser module.config.php)

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'zfcuser' => 'My\Controller\UserController',
    ),
),
```

Then you can overwrite your action and make them return json using Zend\View\Model\JsonModel.

Hope it helps.

Cheers.